# JavaScript loop push to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, push

I am attempting to push all numbers divisible by 3 into a new array "threes" but have hit a wall with why this code is not working.

```
var numbers = function () {
  var threes =[]
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (iLoveThree[i] % 3 === 0){
      threes.push(numbers[i])
    }
  }
  return threes
}
```

Comment: are those <br> tags part of your code or is that a formatting issue?

Comment: Oops, I assumed that the `<br>` was to get line-breaks when simple Markdown would do.

Comment: Where do you have your numbers array?

Comment: Looks like they are defining `numbers` as a function and treating it like an array inside that function.

Comment: Should the for said: `for (i = 0; i < iLoveThree.length; i++)` instead of `numbers.length`?. Just guessing because of the `if (iLoveThree[i] % 3 === 0)`

Comment: Looks like a simple error. You are bounding `i` to `numbers.length`, yet you are looking in the array `iLoveThree`, not `numbers`'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be simpler just to use a filter on numbers

```
var threes = numbers.filter(function(number) {
  return number % 3 === 0;
});
```

Comment: Rolled-back my edit in case the prototype editing bothered some developers (to be be honest it is not universally regarded as a good idea), here is a JSFiddle explaining the code https://jsfiddle.net/ekkk4e53/

Comment: That works too, I'm always scared of extending native object prototypes doe

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed your problem, create a new html file and type this :

```
<!doctype html>
<HTML>

    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT>
            (function(){
                var numbers = function (iLoveThree) {
                    var threes =[];
                    for (i = 0; i < iLoveThree.length; i++) {
                        if (iLoveThree[i] % 3 === 0){
                            threes.push(iLoveThree[i]);
                        }
                      }
                    return threes;
                }
                alert(numbers([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
            })();
        </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Hope it helps :)
Explaination :
 - You need to include function parameter, this parameter will be accessed inside the function (the parameter is named iLoveThree)
 - You were using numbers variable, but this variable had not been declared before, and I fixed this by changing from numbers to iLoveThree
 - You missed several ; (semicolon), it's simple but will cause you a lot of trouble

PS : Thanks to [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) for reminding me about giving explaination.

Comment: Thank you! It's the small things I always over look that trip me up.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your example:

- You have named your function "numbers", but then also reference a non-existing array called "numbers" inside the function
- iLoveThree is being referenced as an array, but was never declared

Depending on the needs of your application, you might need to either get all numbers divisible by three that are between a minimum & maximum value, or you might need to pluck divisible-by-three numbers from a pre-defined array. I have included examples for both scenarios in the code below:

```js
var isDivisibleByThree = function(num){
  return i % 3 === 0;
}

var getThrees = function (min, max) {
  // given a numeric min and max value,
  // return all numbers from a minimum to a maximum value that are divisible by three
  var threes =[];
  for (i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    if (isDivisibleByThree(i)){
      threes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return threes;
}

var getThreesFromArray = function(numbers){
  // given an array of numbers, 
  // return a subset of that array including  only numbers divisible by 3
  var threes = [];
  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (isDivisibleByThree(numbers[i])){
      threes.push(i);
    }
  }
  return threes;
                 
}
var fromZeroTo50 = getThrees(0, 50);
var fromArray = getThreesFromArray([5, 0, 6, 17, 12, 4, 18]);

// Grab example values and display them in the HTML for demonstration purposes
document.getElementById("fromZeroTo50").innerHTML = fromZeroTo50.join(",");
document.getElementById("fromArray").innerHTML = fromArray.join(",");
```

```html
<h2>Get all threes from 0 to 50: </h2>
<div id="fromZeroTo50"></div>

<h2>Get threes from a pre-defined array: </h2>
<div id="fromArray"></div>
```

Comment: @RobG- you are absolutely right:) Updated with vanilla JS.